# plot of multiple series in R with dates

Tags: r, date, plot, time-series

I would like to create d plots including "dailydata", "MAw" and "average":
where "dailydata" are

```
dailydata <- structure(list(CREDIT.AGRICOLE = c(0.0129, 0.0132, 0.0136, 0.0125, 0.0118, 
0.0114, 0.0114, 0.0106, 0.0107, 0.0116, 0.0122, 0.0126, 0.0137, 0.0141,0.0137), 
SOCIETE.GENERAL = c(0.0178, 0.0182, 0.0187, 0.0175, 0.0167, 0.0165, 0.0160, 0.0155, 0.0155,
0.0162, 0.0182, 0.0195, 0.0205, 0.0207, 0.0201)),
.Names = c("CREDIT.AGRICOLE", "SOCIETE.GENERAL"),
row.names = c("18/11/2008", "19/11/2008", "20/11/2008", "21/11/2008", "22/11/2008", 
"23/11/2008", "24/11/2008", "25/11/2008", "26/11/2008", "27/11/2008", "28/11/2008",
"29/11/2008", "30/11/2008", "01/12/2008", "02/12/2008"), class = "data.frame")
```

and "MAw" and "average" I obtain like this

```
w <- 3                       #MA(w)
n <- length(dailydata[,1])+0 #length of data
d <- length(dailydata[1,])+0 #nr of obligors

#extract row and col names
obligorname <- colnames(dailydata)
dates <- rownames(dailydata) 

# calculate moving average ma(w) from daily data
#--------------------------------------------
MAw <- vector()
for(j in seq(from=1, to=d, 1)) #1,2
   {
   vec_MAw <- vector()

   for (i in seq(from=1, to=n-w+1, 1)) #1,2,..., 13
      {
      mean <- sum(dailydata[i:(w-1+i),j])/w
      vec_MAw <- rbind(vec_MAw, mean)
      }
   MAw <- cbind( MAw, vec_MAw)
   }

#name rows and cols
colnames(MAw) <- obligorname
rownames(MAw) <- dates[w:n]

#calculate average
#-----------------
average <- vector()
for(j in seq(from=1, to=d, 1)) # 1, 2
   {
   obligor_average <- sum(dailydata[1:n,j])/n
   average <- cbind(average, obligor_average) 
    }

#name rows and cols
colnames(average) <- obligorname
rownames(average) <- dates[n]
```

I would like to have d plots (one for each obligor, in this example d=2).

Firstly, on x axis, each of these plots should have only few dates which are perpendicular to the x axis.

Secondly, in the figure,

- the series from "dailydata" should start at start date (18/11/2008) and end at end date (02/12/2008)
- the series from "MAw" should start at "w-th date" (here w=3, therefore 20/11/2008) and finish at end date (02/12/2008)
- there should be a horizontal line for the average value

The only thing which I have is this,

```
for (i in seq(from=1, to=d, 1)) 
   {
    plot( dailydata[,i], main= obligorname[i], type = "l", col="red", las=1, 
          ylab="dailydata", xlab="time", ylim = c(0, max(dailydata[i])))
    abline(h=average[,i], col="black")
    lines(MAw[,i], col="blue")
   }
```

which does not give the figure I would like to obtain since the MAw serie should be shifted to the right and there are no dates on the x axis.

I am new to SO and to R and maybe this is not the minimum amount of info necessary to describe my problem. Anyway, what do you suggest?

Should I use as.Date for dates and plot.ts? Or should I use ggplot2? Or something else? And how?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: You will want to reshape your data into a long form (perhaps using `tidyr::gather`) and then you can use plot to add a `geom_line()` for each series (assuming you want to plot using [ggplot2](http://docs.ggplot2.org/)).

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, and reproducible example that anyone else can simply copy and paste into their R session to run.  All library statements and inputs need to be included.  Cut down your data to the minimum needed to illustrate the problem and if your input is `x` then show it by displaying the output of `dput(x)` in your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for general advice and see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for more R oriented advice on how to ask a question on SO.

Comment: Thank you, I included the input as well.